# Shuffle a sentence while retaining whitespace

Tags: python, regex, shuffle

I would like to shuffle letters in my sentence but without interfering with whitespace (Or "_" in my case)

Say my sentence was:

```
sentence = "a_b_c_d"
```

How would I retain the _ in the same position, but shuffle the a, b, c, and d?

Outcome would be something like:

```
sentence = "b_c_a_d"
```

Or something of the likes.

Comment: Split by `_`, shuffle, join by `_`.

Comment: @ndn Could you give an example of "join by"?

Comment: I will assume that you've already attempted this yourself. I mean...why would you ask us to write code for you, right? Anyway...where in your attempted solution are you having trouble?

Answer (score 5):

```
import random

text = text.split("_")
random.shuffle(text)
text = "_".join(text)
```